# Open a new site, scrollbar at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, scrollbar

I will at my forum-system when I'm opening a new site that the scrollbar is at the bottom of the site, so that I don't have to scroll down. I have no ideas how to make a code for this, because I'm not the pro in JavaScript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to place a bookmark at the bottom of the page. Example:

```
<a id="bottom"></a>
```

When you open the page, include the bookmark as hash. Example:

```
<a href="showitem.html#bottom">show</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to complete the task:

> Use this code in css

```
<style type="text/css"> body{overflow-x:hidden;} *{ overflow-x:hidden;} html, div, span, p, label, textarea{ overflow-x:hidden; } </style>
```

> You don't need to use JavaScript to hide **bottom scrollbar** in the html page